# Validation with join clause Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, left-join

I need to validate products and subproducts. The subproducts need to unique just for his parent product. For example:

```
Product1 - > subproduct1;

Product2 - > subproduct1
```

I try something like this :

```
Rule::unique('subproducts')->where(function ($query) {
       $query->leftJoin('products', function ($join) {
          return $join->on('products.id', '=', 'subproducts.product_id');
                    });
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Rule::unique('subproducts')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->has('product'); 
});
```